# How to change dynamically class attribute in Vue $ref object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I got an instance of vue object that in code I'm adding a class:

```
this.$refs.myrefs[0].$el.classList.add('className');
```

But I would like also in code to change something inside 'className':

```
.className {  
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 100px;
}
```

How can I do that? I want to change 'top' and 'left' which are changing according to mouse move position on screen. any idea? How I can access to the same class and change its attributes value? the className is something that being changed.

Comment: you mean changing the style not the class !

Comment: Yes, but dynamically and conditionally, since it should be only for a specific DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that actually you just need binding style
check [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

```
<div v-bind:style="styleObject"></div>

data: {
  styleObject: {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }
}
```

and then with mouse move you need just to get mouse position and update that object
as an example

```
this.styleObject.left = mouseLeft
this.styleObject.top = mouseTop
```

if you have many of that styles for different DOM elements, so I recommend
to use pure JS

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.top = mouseTop
document.getElementById("elementId").style.left = mouseLeft
```

or

```
document.querySelector(".className").style.top = mouseTop
document.querySelector(".className").style.left = mouseLeft
```

Comment: isn't manipulating the dom  directly inefficient, why not use $refs?